# On finding difficult precalculus- level questions

Tags: algebra-precalculus, reference-request

My brother is a sophomore taking Precalculus and like me, has a very difficult and challenging math teacher. I guess he's a little internet shy so I've taken the liberty of coming here and asking for him.

Are there any books or websites that provide very challenging precalculus problems? It would be even better if there were challenging problems not just associated with the stereotypical (pre)calculus concepts (derivatives, integrals, etc.) but problems that deal with foundational Algebra 2 concepts as well (trig, radicals, hyperbolic functions, etc.).

We both believe the only way to survive these difficult math problems is to get exposed to as much as possible out there.

I've asked the same exact question before, but this one is regarding precalculus rather than Calc BC.

Comment: there are hundreds thousands questions here and on math overflow. Do you need more ? You'll find many links to books in their contexts.

Comment: try http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/

Comment: @DavidQuinn -- This is exactly the kind of thing I'm looking for! Thanks so much!